# @media print page breaks getting ignored when printing an html form placed in content editor webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, cewp, printing

When I add the following styling to my html page,

```
@media print {

.pdf-break-after {
    page-break-after: always !important;    
 }

 }
```

Adding this in a content editor webpart. When I try to print the page using ctrl+p , the page breaks are getting ignored. I am not able to figure out the reason.

Why this strange behavior, any suggestions most welcomed on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this issue. The css wasn't getting applied. The problem was with the web-part. The parent div of the webpart had float property applied. I had to set it to none. There on it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Chrome and Firefox with the latest updates, it does not work.

But it works when using IE 11.

You can try the IE to see if it works.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Found multiple threads about `page-break-after` not working in Chrome issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871451/page-break-after-does-not-work-in-chrome